# Accessing TcxGrid controls from a Delphi application from c# using WinAPI

Tags: c#, delphi, winapi

We need to get the value of some controls of a Delphi application from c# . We have used **SendMessage** and **WM_GETTEXT** for getting the text in a text

However we have **DataGrid (TcxGrid)** in the Delphi application... We are unable to iterate through the rows and  read the value of columns in a row...  Any idea on how this can be done

Comment: You are probably out of luck here. Pure delphi controls don't support automation out of the box.

Comment: Of course if you have the delphi code you can add automation support

Comment: I would build in som automation in the program and read the values out of the Dataset. Have you thought about an export?

And if thats not an option you are left with sending keyboard short cuts to your grid.

Comment: Do you have the source code of the Delphi app? Can you change it?

Comment: No I do not have the source... The app was a provided by the client... I tried with UI Path , the screen scraping library... it was able to get the contents as a string...

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion you can use the C# control class of AutoIT.https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/. I used it successfully to automate several complex applications written in different languages. It is easy to understand and it hides all the complexity of SendMessage and other gory details and gets the job done.

Comment: Not going to be useful here. How will it extract data from the control?

Comment: some of working examples for Excel are here https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Excel_RangeRead.htm. The tool is extremely versatile and it supports reading text from controls.

Comment: How is it going to read text from this particular control. A pure Delphi control that doesn't support automation? A control that offers no programmatic means for external apps to read its contents.

Comment: You are right. The control is not derived from a native OS control. but still AutoIt can help by sending keystrokes and copy data to clipboard and process it from there. A reference to a similar question is here http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/69453-how-to-get-text-from-devexpress-grid/ .  Unfortunately it does not give to many details on how this can be implemented.