# Constant messages to retrieve information from a Delphi TcxGrid by using SendMessage API

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, autoit

I'm trying to manipulating a TcxGrid in an application developed in Delphi using AutoIt.
AutoIt have a lot of custom libraries but any of them related with TcxGrid because this object is not a standard Windows object. I could use any other IDE or programming language (C#, C++, even Delphi) but I'll be stuck at the same problem: How to retrieve information from this control?
Basicaly to comunicate with other processes we use:

`LRESULT SendMessage(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)`

But the real problem is how to know the constant messages used in Delphi objects.
Anybody have any idea where to find the constants used to communicate with a TcxGrid object? I already considered creating a loop and increasing the message value and testing it one by one, but this will take a loooong time.

**Other related searches:**
Windows documentation for SendMessage:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage
Windows documentation for a ComboBox (just as example):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bumper-combobox-control-reference-messages
Similar doubt 1:
[Accessing TcxGrid controls from a Delphi application from c# using WinAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611570/accessing-tcxgrid-controls-from-a-delphi-application-from-c-sharp-using-winapi)
Similar doubt 2:
[Retrieve a ComboBox counts and items by using SendMessage API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311818/retrieve-a-combobox-counts-and-items-by-using-sendmessage-api)

Comment: You would probably to ask Devex tech support about this.

Comment: There might be ways to do particular things, but why would you assume that there would be a communication protocol using windows messages for a particular proprietary control? I suspect there isn't.

Comment: I just did a search through the source code of last month's update of TcxGrid and as far as I can see, although it implements a few standard Windows/Delphi messages (e.g. CM_BIDIMODECHANGED, CM_DIALOGCHAR and CM_DEFERUPDATES), it does not define any custom messages of its own.

Comment: You're going to have to be using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). You can quickly verify, whether the intended target supports the required interfaces by running Inspect.exe from the Windows SDK. If this doesn't accomplish what you need, then nothing will. Throwing random messages at a control certainly doesn't get you anywhere near a solution.

Comment: I installed the Windows SDK but the actual version doesn't provide the "Isnpect.exe" anymore, so I installed the "Accessibility Insights for Windows" that is recommended by MS as the successor, also I tried "Windows Detective". Both tools didn't get any good clue on how to manipulate the TcxGrid, there are just a few properties available. So... bad news... probably there is no way to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Only access to source codes will show a complete list of messages used. Any old versions would be a good solution too.
2. All Delphi `TWinControl` descendant components support standard Windows messages such as `WM_*` (eg, `WM_CHAR`, `WM_LBUTTONUP` etc). Delphi also uses special `CM_*` messages. The list of messages is available in the Delphi source. The main modules are `Winapi.Messages` and `Vcl.Controls`.

Third-party developers rarely add their messages. This is usually not required for data exchange within the Delphi language.

3. The hard way is to track all the messages sent by the window when working. Use the `SetWindowsHookEx` function with parameters `WH_GETMESSAGE`, `WH_CALLWNDPROC`. Be mindful of the `LPARAM` and `WPARAM` values. They also contain important information.

Addition: Grids usually use built-in components (`EDIT`, `COMBOBOX` etc) to enter information. When they are visible you can also send messages to them.

Comment: This might be true of standard Delphi controls, but the Developer Express TcxGrid is a long way from being a standard Delphi control.

Comment: Unfortunately you need source codes or use SetWindowsHookEx.

Comment: Yes, TcxGrid is not a standard control in any way. Unfortunately I don`t have access to source code.